# MongoDb C# queries, where clause

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am working with `MongoDb`, and is using `PredicateBuilder` class for creating where clause dynamically IN C#. But the exception gets generated as :

> [System.ArgumentException] {"Unsupported where clause: ."} ,

and the dynamically generated where clause is

```
{c => (True AndAlso Invoke(c => (c.ID == value(ASP.search_aspx).txtid.Text), c))} ,
```

Query Used:

```
var result = collection.AsQueryable<USER>()
                      .Where(where_clause)
                      .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.COMPANYNAME, c.EMAIL 
                       }).Take(100).ToList();
```

collection is the instance is `MongoCollection`.

Code for creating `where_clause`:

```
var where_clause = PredicateBuilder.True<GLUSR_USR>();

//object result=0;
if ((txtGlid.Text).Trim() != "")
{
    where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_ID == txtGlid.Text);
}
if ((txtEmailid.Text).Trim() != "")
{
    where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_EMAIL == txtEmailid.Text);
}
if ((txtPhone.Text).Trim() != "")
{
    where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_PH_NUMBER == txtPhone.Text);
}
if ((txtMobile.Text).Trim() != "")
{
    where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_PH_MOBILE == txtMobile.Text);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you build up `where_clause` please?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `Invoke`, it looks like a reference  to `(ASP.search_aspx).txtid.Text` has been captured in the closure, rather than evaluating the value at this time. Can I ask you to evaluating the text box value explicitly in a local, to prevent any chance of the Expression parser making a mess:

```
if (txtGlid.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    string s = txtGlid.Text;
    where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_ID == s);
}
```

<del>it possibly means that you've added `where c.ID == txtid.Text` as a predicate, instead of `where c.ID == txtid.Text()` in your dynamic builder. Passing in the string value should generate the simpler predicate `(True AndAlso c.ID == "someLiteralValue")`, which hopefully can be parsed by the `Linq` provider.</del>

Comment: but the same is working with the List i.e when collection is of List type

Comment: And also 'Text' is the property of 'txtid' not the function

Comment: Thanks, have tried your suggestion, but its not working, same error...  where_clause = where_clause.And(c => c.GLUSR_USR_ID == "10387904");

Comment: The mongo query provider might not be able to understand  [PredicateBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7072202/314291) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759613/has-anyone-been-able-to-use-successfully-predicatebuilder-from-albahari-com-agai). You might need to build the dynamic `Expression<>`s yourself :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AsExpandable()`:

```
var result = collection.AsQueryable<USER>()
                       .AsExpandable()
                       .Where(where_clause)
                       .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.COMPANYNAME, c.EMAIL 
                       }).Take(100).ToList();
```

`AsExpandable()` can be found in [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

Comment: collection is MongoCollection type, it doesn't support AsExpandable(),

Comment: @ank_UD But you are using it on a `IQueryable<USER>`, so that can't be the problem. Does it work when you manually set the where clause?