# Linq to SQL and Codepages in generated SQL

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

We have a poorly-performing query in L2S.  The actual query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
    ([ColA] IN (@p0) AND ColB = @p1) 
    OR ColB IN (@p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [220]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 14; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [CountryDefault]
-- @p2: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
-- @p4: Input NVarChar (Size = 7; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [WF1 1XU]
-- @p5: Input NVarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [WF1]
-- Context: ProfiledSqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1
```

One problem is a merge-sort as a result of the `OR`, but we're looking into that.

The other problem is more interesting.  One of our DBAs pointed out there's quite a performance hit in the codepage conversion between the `NVarChar` parameters and the column they're being compare with `VarChar`.

The weird thing is how L2S chose for some of those parameters to be `NVarChar`, and the `p1` parameter to be `VarChar`.  In the code they are all strings, although `p1` is a string literal while the others are variables.  Notice they're all being compared to the same column (`ColB`) so it's nothing to do with the column datatype.

How does L2s decide what datatype to use when generating the query, based on the values passed-in?  If possible, how do I control that?

Comment: Can you post the LINQ query that generates this SQL?

Comment: This is possibly related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d8577454-ebca-4697-80ef-73b7620e87a4

Comment: @p1 is compared against ColB, not ColA.

Comment: Here is another realted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699382/linq-to-sql-nvarchar-problem